# Error: NG0203 , Nx monorepo with module federation ( angular projects )

Tags: angular, webpack-dev-server, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation, nx-monorepo

im using Nx monorepo to make a module federation projet with 1 host & 5 remotes ( angular projects ) and they are all using the same package.json with angular version 16.2.0

Im facing a probleme of this error : NG0203 , when im deploying the projet in my prod environnement.

> This is a screenshot of the error : [Error: NG0203](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgVQv.png)

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOL6y.png)

i have made a lot of search but no result.

Thanks for your help.
PS: (sorry for my english)

i have tried to share the "@angular/common" and inject it into the webpack config.

Comment: hey, have you managed to figure out and solution or workaround?